# R diverging bar chart

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following tibble. I want to be able to take the s16 values and subtract the v20 values. From this I wanted to create a  Diverging Bar chart as some of the values will be positive and some negative

```
## # A tibble: 18 x 4
## # Groups:   s16 [11]
##    s16        v16    s20       v20
##    <fct>      <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>
##  1 A         1017   <NA>          NA
##  2 D         152    <NA>          NA
##  3 F         15629  <NA>          NA
##  4 GG        15437  <NA>          NA
##  5 GPS       1588   GPS          3650
##  6 FIND      15853  <NA>          NA
##  7 LAB       3220   LAB          1548
##  8 N         2165   <NA>          NA
##  9 SFT       5755   <NA>          NA
## 10 P         3455   <NA>          NA
## 11 <NA>        NA    U           1058
## 12 <NA>        NA    F           13697
## 13 <NA>        NA    GG          10893
## 14 <NA>        NA    FIND        16476
## 15 <NA>        NA    SFT          8464
## 16 <NA>        NA    DP           3623
## 17 <NA>        NA    BP           932
## 18 <NA>        NA    NA            NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something odd is going on with your data - to be specific, it is not really tidy because you have two observations per row. I think it would help if you convert it to three columns: the group, the v16 value, and the v20 value, thus making it tidy. In psuedocode something like this should work, assuming your data frame is in data:

```
data1 <- data %<%
  filter(!is.na(s16)) %>% 
  select(s16, v16)
data2 <- data %>% 
  filter(!is.na(s20)) %>% 
  select(s20, v20)

data <- data1 %>% 
  left_join(data2, by = c(s16 = s20)) %>% 
  mutate(diff = v20 - v16)

data %>%
  ggplot() %>% 
  geom_col(aes(s16, diff))
```

Comment: When I try and plug in this code, I keep getting the following error.      Error in standardise_join_by(by, x_names = x_names, y_names = y_names) : 
  object 's20' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... left_join.data.frame -> join_mutate -> join_cols -> standardise_join_by
In addition: Warning messages:

Answer (score 0):

The solution by Carey above works.
I had to change the following

```
data <- data1 %>% 
  left_join(data2, by = c("s16" = "s20")) %>%
```